# HOWTO transfer a request made to an Apache server to an IIS server without using a URL redirect?

Tags: apache, iis, iis-7, redirect, apache2

My Apache 2.2.9 runs on Debian Lenny 5.0.1 with 2 network interfaces, one interface has a public IP and hostname, the other is not configured. This machine caters to services that run on the LAMP stack.

There is a Windows Server 2008 SP2 machine running IIS 7 that serves our ASP.net needs. The box can be configured to be either on a local or a public IP and has 2 network interfaces as well.

Both the servers serve over SSL and Apache is public facing.

Is there a way when a request such as https://foo.com/contentfromiis/ is made the browser can serve contents from the IIS server without using a redirect and transferring to https://bar.com/iwastransferedhere/. In other words the user must not /experience/ any switch happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, I believe you may be able to use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) to do what you want. Basically, Apache would act as a "reverse proxy" for the requests that you actually want to serve from IIS. Note that a reverse proxy isn't like a normal HTTP proxy. From the `mod_proxy` docs:

> A reverse proxy ... appears to the
>   client just like an ordinary web
>   server. No special configuration on
>   the client is necessary. The client
>   makes ordinary requests for content in
>   the name-space of the reverse proxy.
>   The reverse proxy then decides where
>   to send those requests, and returns
>   the content as if it was itself the
>   origin.

Comment: Thanks Laurence, that addresses my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what Laurence Gonsalves says.  Here is a simple as simple can be configuration file that I've taken from a caching reverse proxy server of mine.  You should be able to work in some URL matching but I've not done that myself.

```
# httpd *reverse proxy caching server* config file for apache httpd 2.2
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2"
#must exist, no reason to have anythign in it    
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs"

Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.1.33:80
ServerAdmin stu@thompson.name
ServerName proxy.server.com

LoadModule auth_module modules/mod_auth.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

### PROXY CONFIGURATION  ###
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia On

### VH ###
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.33>
    ProxyPass        /  http://192.168.1.34:80/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.1.34:80/
    LogLevel info
</VirtualHost>

### LOGGING CONFIGURATION ###
# error log will not catch proxied content
ErrorLog logs/error.log
LogLevel info
LogFormat "%{Host}i %v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b  common
CustomLog logs/access.log common
TypesConfig conf/mime.types
```

Comment: Thanks Stu, your config file will be handy as I tweak that to my environment.